# Download and Decompile an Ios app

Tags: decompilation, ios

I want to write an automatic process that downloads an ios app and decompile it?
I couldn't find any source or method to download an ios app without using any Apple Device.

Comment: Where do you mean to download the apps from? The AppStore is the only legal distributor. If its legal in your country, you could use a [shady redistributor](https://www.iphonecake.com/). Apple keeps a very thigh grip on things.

Comment: Without using appstore.

Comment: So you want help hacking Apple's servers?

Comment: nop , just want to download apps and wants to analyse it. I couldn't find any source and method to dowload app without using appstore

Comment: See: that is the point. There are two ways to get these apps: utilizing apple hardware to download apps or to use a service which in turn employs apple hardware to download apps. As for other options, you may have to contact apple yourself.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no way to download apps without a device, since the necessary keys are embedded in the CPU and cannot be extracted using software means (this also prevents offline decryption of apps). However, with a jailbroken device it's possible to simulate user input in the App Store app and download the apps automatically (and then decrypt them). Check [this presentation](https://recon.cx/2017/brussels/resources/slides/RECON-BRX-2017-Analysing_ios_Apps.pdf) ([video](https://recon.cx/media-archive/2017/brx/recon2017-brx-15-lenar-safin-yaroslav-alexandrov-egor-fominykh-alexander-chernov-Analyzing-iOS-apps-road-from-AppStore-to-security-analysis-report.mp4)) from last Recon Brussels for some ideas.